# Put Dictionary in NSTableView in Swift 4

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, nstableview

I want to put dictionary:

```
dict = [["itemId": 21, "itemPrice": 34], ["itemId": 32, "itemPrice": 52]]
```

I have also linked `NSTableView` in my `NSViewController`:

```
class MainViewController: NSViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
      .... 
}
```

The columns Identifiers are same as keys of my dictionary `dict`.

How can I put my dict in a table? And how I can change a values in the table?

Comment: It's Swift. Use `Dictionary` instead.

Comment: Your dictionary is `[[String:Int]]` array. if you use Cocoa Bindings and a custom class you don't need to write any code.

Comment: The fact that it's an array is actually a good thing.  It's an array of dictionaries, so each contained dictionary can match one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa Bindings solution:

1. In the view controller declare a data source array

   ```
   @objc dynamic var items = [["itemId": 21, "itemPrice": 34], ["itemId": 32, "itemPrice": 52]]
   ```
2. In Interface Builder

   - Bind the `Content` of the table view to `View Controller > items`
   - Bind the `Value` of the `Table View Cell` of the first column to `Table Cell View > objectValue.itemId`
   - Bind the `Value` of the `Table View Cell` of the second column to `Table Cell View > objectValue.itemPrice`

   Please note the difference `Table View Cell` and `Table Cell View`. It's crucial.

That's all. No code needed except the single line.

Comment: Thank you! It realy helped!

Answer (score 1):

The model for a table view is an array of objects, each representing a row.

The model for a sectioned table view is an array of arrays of objects.  (the outer array represents sections, and the inner arrays represent rows).

The first job for a table's datasource is to rearrange it's input to be an array.  Dictionaries provide allKeys and allValues method which answer arrays of keys and values respectively.  That's normally where one begins.